# Is 1.abc!``!+123 a valid file name?

Tags: bash, filesystem

Is this a valid file name ``` 1.abc!``!+123 ``` in Ubuntu?

I issued the command

```
rm 1.abc!``!+123
```

and got error message

```
-bash: !``!+123: event not find
```

Why? How to I delete the file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just simply ``` rm '1.abc!``!+123' ```. Note about `'`

**Note**:Quoting is used to remove the special meaning of certain characters or words to the shell. Quoting can be used to disable  special  treatment for special characters, to prevent reserved words from being recognized as such, and to prevent parameter expansion. Some special characters are: $ ` " !

Comment: The `!` invokes the Bash history expansion so it has to be protected by quotes or a preceding `\`

Answer (score 7):

Yes, that is a valid file name. However, the shell treats those as special characters, so to use them in a file command, you will need to escape them using `'`:

```
rm '1.abc!``!+123'
```

According to the [bash manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/bash.1.html),

> **!**  Start a history substitution, except when followed by  a  blank,
>          newline,  carriage return, = or ( (when the extglob shell option
>          is enabled using the shopt builtin).

And

> #### Command Substitution
>
> Command  substitution  allows  the  output  of a command to replace the
>   command name.  There are two forms:
>
> ```
> $(command)
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> `command`
> ```

So if you want to use the `!` or `` ` `` characters as regular characters, you need to escape them using `'` so the shell doesn't try to start a history or command substitution.